# Logging into empathy after enabling two stage verification in Google

Tags: empathy, google-talk

I have enabled two stage verification in my Google account.

This has prevented me from logging into gtalk via empathy.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

1) go to https://www.google.com/accounts/ManageAccount

2) click "Authorizing applications & sites" (https://www.google.com/accounts/IssuedAuthSubTokens)

3) use the "Generate new application-specific password" feature

4) add that new password to Empathy